# I feel someone has copied data from my computer via wifi. Is that possible?

Tags: wifi-transfer

Can someone copy files from my computer to theirs remotely or via WiFi while visiting my home? Can they access passwords via WiFi? If yes, how can I tell if data was copied??

Comment: Is your home wireless network secured? E.g., does it use [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy), which has known vulnerabilities, or [WPA or WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) for security or is it an unsecured network that anyone can join without knowing an access key? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Can you supply more information regarding your wifi? Is it password protected? do people know the password? do you have folders shared on your computer?

Answer (score 5):

Yep, if you have open shares on your computer and lax security.

And no, you can't tell what's been copied.

Use WPA2 on your WIFI, don't share the pass phrase with anyone you don't trust.

Don't complain about Microsoft's increasing insistence that you use a password to log onto your computer before using it. It's there to protect any shares by requiring authentication to access them, not just for locking out someone sitting down at your system and using it.

Newer WIFI routers have guest access mode, get one and only give that pass phrase out to visitors to your home.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. Anything is possible with Internet. Hackers usually do this. make sure your ports are all stealth. Go to grc shields up! To make sure your ports are not opened. If a port is closed and you haven't used it then it's possible that something else is behind it. Who ever says closed ports are safe has no clue!

Comment: Doesn't really apply if the user is already inside the firewall.

Comment: Yeah check my recent post. Nothing can be as bad as what I'm going through literally no one can help me remove my hacker. The only option I have an constantly hear is go to the cops.

Comment: Frankly, this is nothing more than FUD.